# Context sensitve code generation with grako

Tags: python, codegen, grako

I'm in a situation where I've built an abstract syntax tree (AST) with grako's model builder semantics. Now I need to generate javascript code from that AST. I have defined several templates, but I realized not all cases can be handled with simple templates. The concrete rule I'm stuck with is:

```
fcall::FunctionCall   = name:identifier '(' ','.{args:expression} ')' ;
```

This rule matches both, simple function calls and constructor calls, as there is no way to lexically determine which is which, it depends if there is a class with that name is defined within that scope.

So e.g. "a = Func();"

in javascript the two cases require different syntax ("a = new Func();" or "a = Func();")

So I need a symbol table to keep track which is which. Is there a way to achive this with grako?

#### Aditional Info:

My idea on how to do this:
Create a walker class, that builds up a symbol table and when it handles a FunctionCall object, check if it is actually a constructor call and in that case replace the FunctionCall node with a ConstructorCall node. Then simply have two templates for the two.

What I don't like about the approach is that it feels too separated and it requires a new class for each template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the template and the rendered fields at runtime. Because an instance of the `ModelRenderer` is created for each AST node, the changes you make affect only the rendering of that single `Node`:

```
def render_fields(self, fields):
   if self.is_constructor_call():
      self.template = self.constructor_template
```

Note that the assignment is to an instance variable, and that `ClassName.template` remains the same.